# Python: read a percentage value from excel using xlrd

Tags: python, xlrd

I am trying to read percentage value from excel using xlrd. but the output keeps coming as 1.0. Is there a way that I can load it as a percentage without the value being changed?

Below is what I have in my excel sheet

[image]

code:

```
for r in range(1, xlsheet.nrows):
    num_cols = xlsheet.ncols
    print('-'*40)
    print('Row: %s' % r)
    for col_idx in range(1, num_cols):​for r in range(1, xlsheet.nrows):
    num_cols = xlsheet.ncols
    print('-'*40)
    print('Row: %s' % r)
    for col_idx in range(1, num_cols):
        cell_obj = xlsheet.cell(r, col_idx)
        print('Column:[%s] cell_obj: [%s]' % (col_idx, cell_obj))
```

output I am getting:

```
Row: 2
Column:[1] cell_obj: [number:1.0]
Column:[2] cell_obj: [number:1.0]
Column:[3] cell_obj: [number:1.0]
Column:[4] cell_obj: [number:1.0]
Column:[5] cell_obj: [number:1.0]
Column:[6] cell_obj: [number:1.0]
Column:[7] cell_obj: [number:1.0]
Column:[8] cell_obj: [number:1.0]
Column:[9] cell_obj: [number:1.0]
Column:[10] cell_obj: [number:1.0]
Column:[11] cell_obj: [number:1.0]
Column:[12] cell_obj: [number:1.0]
```

Comment: Is it always 1.0? Or is it 0.5 when the percentage is 50% for example?

Comment: it comes as 0.5 if it is 50%. i tried to format the value but gives me an error using .format(val *100)

Comment: I would expect `'{}'.format(cell_obj.value *100)` to give you your expected result. Does it not? What error do you get?

Comment: I was multiplying (cell_obj * 100) instead of (cell_obj.value *100). works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use pandas to convert the whole excel to a data frame, something like:

```
excel_dataframe = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=s)
```

and then use a apply map to convert to string.

```
 excel_dataframe = excel_dataframe.applymap(str)
```

This will convert all the cells in the excel to string, that way you get a string object and the correct value

Comment: thanks Rahul, unfortunately it has to be a python script to run as a schedule.