# How can python read "percentage" from excel file?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file where some of the columns have percent value. I use pd.read_excel to read my file, but it gives me 1 instead of 100%. Is there any way python can read all percent value?

I have referred to [Python: read a percentage value from excel using xlrd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63810700/python-read-a-percentage-value-from-excel-using-xlrd) but it did not give me the desired result.

How can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Multiply by 100?

Comment: If you open excel in notepad, you will see 1. you are seeing 100% in excel just because the format in excel.

Answer (score 0):

A percentage is expressed by any value over 1. So a percentage of 50 `(50/100) is 0.5`. A percentage value of 100% `(100/100) is 1`.

To get the percentage, just take the value and multiply it by 100.
Example:
`.5 * 100 = 50` and
`1.0 * 100 = 100`.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48977649/pandas-read-excel-percentages-as-strings), you could specify a converter to `pd.read_excel` by the parameter `converters`.